# The "synchronous" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

From the mysterious/ambiguous tag department, today I stumbled on [synchronous](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synchronous). Just quickly looking at it took out a *sigh* of me. Various things can be synchronous, including

- [(AC) synchronous motors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronous_motor) (for which I just created a [synchronous-motor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synchronous-motor))
- [synchronous rectification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_rectification) which is applied to DC/DC converters, e.g. [synchronous buck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter#Synchronous_rectification)
- [synchronous serial communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronous_serial_communication)
- [synchronous counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter_(digital)#Synchronous_counter)

just to pick those questions where I could tell from the title what they were about. No doubt there are more distinct topics I missed. I think most of these need separate tags, although some are probably too sparsely populated to justify one yet.

Comment: shouldn't that be synchronous-machines not synchronous-motor as all electrical machines can act as a motor or a generator and it is more a term of convenience for what it mostly does.

Comment: @JonRB: probably so... I've only got to question in that tag insofar, so it's not a catastrophe